# Is it possible to wrap .Net core MVC app as dll, add reference to another console application and start from console app?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dll, .net-core, console-application

Dears,

I would like to create few dotnet core MVC apps, and one console app which will start these MVC apps.
Is it possible to wrap all that is needed for running of the MVC app to dll, then add the dll reference to the console app, and start the MVC from console app (the referenced dll)?

Comment: You want a console app to start several websites?

Comment: Is a console app really needed, or would a BAT file work?  You should be able to start the MVC apps from the BAT file like this "dotnet MyApp.dll".  You would have multiple copies of that command on multiple lines referencing the individual DLLs.

Comment: a batch file is also an option. but in the future i would like to create gui and let user decide by checkboxes which apps to start. I am really curious if runnung mvc dll from console app (or any other app) is possuble or not